# Xcode Sanitizer How to Enable

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode12, bounds-checker

Using Xcode 12, Apple Clang Address Sanitizer, I enable... *Enable C++ Container Overflow Checks* (for both Debug and Release).

I wish *Enable C++ Container Overflow Checks* to give me run-time warnings, eg. by translating each `[]` into an `.at()`.

I run a code similar to the below (which comes at the end of a bunch of previous functions calls where the number of elements of `V` can not be known at compile-time.)

```
// V is a container with 100 elements, 
// each element is a pointer to objects with a field f;

auto x = V[200]; // gives no error, no bounds checking (but V.size() is 100)
cout << x->f; // gives error, this object is not valid
```

I do not get the expected result, no run-time bounds checking is done on `V`.

Question: Is *Enable C++ Container Overflow Checks* supposed to give me `.at()` like bounds checking for `[]` access? How may I achieve this?

Comment: This is not your first question. You already should be aware that question about this kind of problems requires [mcve]. Use this to show how to reproduce issue: https://godbolt.org/z/P79Kad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early

To enable this tool, select Address Sanitizer from the Diagnostics section of the appropriate scheme.

[image]

Also, other sanitizer checks may be enabled from that menu.

I have verified that this works, it gives a very detailed account of any violation at runtime.

*Note: The difference from the (non working) approach given in the question is that here the configuration is done in the scheme menu, not in the build settings menu. I have no idea why the latter does not work.*